# Issues with Screen - Running Minecraft in a while loop through a screen session

Tags: bash, while-loop, sh, minecraft

So Earlier today, I changed my startup scripts for my minecraft server. Problem is, after about 3 hours, the screen for it that was open vanished and refuses to appear when using `-ls`. The server is still running and from what I can see below, the screen process should still be active?
`ServerStart.sh` is called during `init`. and originally only contained the while loop.

`ServerStart.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash    
#Check to see if a minecraft screen is already running
lineCount=`screen -r mc | grep "There is no screen to be resumed matching mc." | wc -l`

#Start the minecraft server in a detached screen named "c" if its not running
#Launch the command line interface for minecraft if it is arealdy running.
if [ $lineCount -eq 1 ]
  then
    echo linecount: $lineCount. Starting in a deteched screen named minecraft. Use screen -r minecraft to view.
    screen -dmS mc sh ServerLoop.sh
  else
    echo lineCount: $lineCount. Minecraft is already running. Use screen -r minecraft to view. Running now.
    screen -r mc
fi
```

`ServerLoop.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash
while true
do
java -server -Xms4096m -Xmx16384m -XX:PermSize=512m -d64 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10 -jar FTB.jar nogui
echo Restarting-Give me 90 Seconds.
sleep 10
done
```

Comment: What do you do after running ServerStart.sh the first time? Run `screen -r mc`, run `ServerStart.sh` again, or do you just leave the screen session detatched for three hours?

Comment: ServerStart.sh should start my mc screen and run ServerLoop.sh which should forever keep my server alive and the console viewable through the screen session due to the 'while true' statement, correct?

Why my screen session vanished is beyond me.. Now I've got a server that won't stay dead as it just restarts whenever I try stop it (trying to avoid just forcibly shutting things down) as I can't stop ServerLoop.sh..

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: After it runs on init, I hope never to run anything in relation to it again, unless I check up on it via screen -r mc.

My session was attached and when I returned home, it was not.. Server has been running since without a console.

Comment: Well, if nothing is attached for three hours, if there's nowhere for the server's output to be displayed, it's possible that some buffer is overflowing and the screen process exits or crashes. If that's not the case, and you're not rerunning SeverStart.sh (which might not handle this case correctly) I don't know what could be causing the issue. You can stop the java process by first killing the bash process that restarts it. The bash process will be the parent process of the java process.

Comment: Trying to avoid process killing, to mitigate lost data. But the only change I was considering making was using source over sh, as it would be kept within the same process then.

The point is not to ever need to re-run ServerStart.sh as it just handles screen init and starts the loop.

Comment: Killing the bash process shouldn't lose any data. You should rewrite ServerStart.sh to be just one line if that's all needs to do.

Comment: To my knowledge: Killing the process running the server WILL lose data if it goes down, as it's not cleanly stopped via console. 

Why rewrite it when it should work perfectly? It's not pure simple and straightforward as I prefer to know that when ServerStart.sh is launched on init, it WILL launch and if someone else tries later during their SSH session, it shouldn't do anything bar open the servers screen session.

Comment: The bash process isn't the server process, but if you don't already understand that never mind.

Comment: I apologize Ross, I'd only woken up an hour back and I had misread your posts. I tracked down the loop process using htop and term'd it.

Should I see how it runs using source over sh, keep it to the same process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was getting random additions of ^M whilst transferring via ftp due to writing the scripts in Notepad++. They weren't added to every revision of code though, so it wasn't a consistent thing. They were however stopping start.sh from running without giving any real notion as to why.

For reference to others, the below has been working fine throughout multiple daily restarts for the past 48hrs+, across 2 different servers. Hopefully someone else may find this useful, be it for Minecraft or any other similar task.

`ServerStart.sh`

`#/bin/bash
screen -dmS infitech sh ./start.sh
screen -r infitech`

`start.sh`

`#/bin/bash
while true
do
java -Xms8192m -Xmx10240m -XX:PermSize=512m -jar server-1.7.10-1403.jar nogui -Dfml.queryResult=confirm
echo "Feel Free to CTRL+C to stop the server"
sleep 10
done`